# How do you update the same cell you've entered a value in, based on another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, target, byval

Complete VBA beginner here - I'm trying to update a cell, which I've just entered a value for, based on another cell and its changing value.

So, I enter 100 into A1.

Then, based on the option of typing 3 words in cell C5, I want to multiple A1 by a certain amount.

If I enter 'Normal' into C5, it'll multiple A1 by 1.
If I enter 'Low' into C5, it'll multiple A1 by 0.5.
If I enter 'High' into C5, it'll multiple A1 by 2.

Any help or direction would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a worksheet event handler that triggers when cell C5 value changes

place this code in worksheet code pane (just right click on the tab and select "View Code")

```
Dim myValue As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address <> "$A$1" Then myValue = Range("A1").Value ' keep track of any "original value" changes
    If Target.Address <> "$C$5" Then Exit Sub

    If IsEmpty(myValue) Then myValue = Range("A1").Value ' retrieve the "original value" if not already set

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Normal"
            ' no need to multiply by 1 ...

        Case "Low"
            Range("A1").Value = myValue * 0.5 ' divide "original value"

        Case "High"
            Range("A1").Value = myValue * 2 'multiply "original value"

    End Select

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True       
End Sub
```

Comment: nice use of `CountLarge` and the inclusion of an error-handler *(+1)*

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did not know about Case, will look into it further. I did forget to mention, that each change of C5 should run its calculation off the original value entered into A1.

Comment: see edited code. if it solves your question you could accept the answer to direct future readers, too...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you display the result in another cell like B1?
Then you could just use a simple formula there:

```
=A1*IF($C$5="Low",0.5,IF($C$5="High",2,1))
```

[image]

---

Alternate VBA solution

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) 'you can extend the range to more cells like A1:A10

    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit

        Dim Factor As Double
        Select Case Me.Range("C5").Value 'note this is case sensitive
            Case "Normal": Exit Sub
            Case "Low":    Factor = 0.5
            Case "High":   Factor = 2
        End Select

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedCells.Cells
            If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
                Cell.Value = Cell.Value * Factor
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```